# How to input a boolean to a Simulink C s-function

Tags: boolean, simulink

I can input boolean data into a C s-function by defining it as an int32 (see code below). How do I input boolean data with SS_BOOLEAN or SS_UINT8 type? I specified the signal data type explicitly in my Simulink model and s-function but when I defined the data as boolean or uint8, I got strange numbers instead of 1 or 0.

```
 static void mdlInitializeSizes( SimStruct *S )
 {
     ...
     ssSetInputPortRequiredContiguous(S, 0, true);
     ssSetInputPortDataType(S, 0, SS_INT32);
     ...
 }
 static void mdlOutputs( SimStruct *S, int_T tid )
 {
     const int *myBoolean = (const int*) ssGetInputPortSignal( S, 0 );
     ...
 }
```

**Update (20 May 2011):** I tried the [solution proposed by MikeT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5897548/how-to-input-a-boolean-to-a-simulink-c-s-function/5905886#5905886) to no avail. As output I was expecting [10 20 30] but got [1 2 3]. Below is the Simulink model, the ouput on command window and s-function code:

[image]

```
 static void mdlOutputs( SimStruct *S, int_T tid )
 {
    InputBooleanPtrsType useData1 = (InputBooleanPtrsType) ssGetInputPortSignalPtrs( S, 0 );
    InputBooleanPtrsType useData2 = (InputBooleanPtrsType) ssGetInputPortSignalPtrs( S, 1 );
    const double *data1 = (const double*) ssGetInputPortSignal( S, 2 );
    const double *data2 = (const double*) ssGetInputPortSignal( S, 3 );


    double *outputs = (double *) ssGetOutputPortRealSignal( S, 0 );

    double *data;
    int i;

    if (*useData1){data = data1;}
    else if (*useData2){data = data2;}

    //assign outputs:
    for (i=0; i<3; i++){outputs[i] = data[i];}

    printf("useData1  = %d\n", *useData1);
    printf("useData2  = %d\n", *useData2);  
 }

 static void mdlInitializeSizes( SimStruct *S )
 {  
    int iPort;
    if ( !ssSetNumInputPorts( S, 4 ) )
    {
        return;
    }

    ssSetInputPortDataType(S, 0, SS_BOOLEAN);
    ssSetInputPortDataType(S, 1, SS_BOOLEAN);
    ssSetInputPortDataType(S, 2, SS_DOUBLE);
    ssSetInputPortDataType(S, 3, SS_DOUBLE);

    ssSetInputPortWidth( S, 0, 1 );
    ssSetInputPortWidth( S, 1, 1 );
    ssSetInputPortWidth( S, 2, 3 );
    ssSetInputPortWidth( S, 3, 3 );

    for (iPort = 0; iPort < 4 ; iPort++)
    {       
        ssSetInputPortRequiredContiguous(S, iPort, true); /*direct input signal access*/
        ssSetInputPortDirectFeedThrough( S, iPort, 1 ); 
    }

    if ( !ssSetNumOutputPorts( S, 1 ) )
    {
        return;
    }
    ssSetOutputPortDataType(S, 0, SS_DOUBLE);
    ssSetOutputPortWidth( S, 0, 3 );

    ssSetNumSampleTimes( S, 1 );
    ssSetOptions( S, SS_OPTION_EXCEPTION_FREE_CODE );
 }
```

Answer (score 6):

There is a demo s-function in Simulink called sfun_dtype_io.c that shows how to set the data type of inputs and outputs.  From that demo, here's how it handles a boolean input, although this is not the only way to do this,

```
static void mdlInitializeSizes(SimStruct *S) {
...
/* input 2 is a boolean scalar signal. */
ssSetInputPortWidth(             S, 2, 1 );
ssSetInputPortDataType(          S, 2, SS_BOOLEAN );
ssSetInputPortDirectFeedThrough( S, 2, TRUE );
...
}

static void mdlOutputs (SimStruct *S, int_T tid) {
...
/* The control port is a boolean signal */
InputBooleanPtrsType u2Ptr = (InputBooleanPtrsType)
                                       ssGetInputPortSignalPtrs(S,2);
...
}
```

Comment: To open this example use sfunddg_cb_edit('sfun_dtype_io');